# why does not eclips know cout and cin in my code?

Tags: c++

I am new in c++, I want to write my program with eclips but it does not know cout and cin however I add include
This is my code:

```
class READY {
public:
READY();
virtual ~READY();
#include <iostream.h>
int main (){
cout<<"hello";
 }


 };

#endif /* READY_H_ */
```

Answer (score 5):

Move the include and `main` outside the class and qualify `cout` with `std::`:

```
#include <iostream>

class READY {
public:
  READY();
  virtual ~READY();
};


int main (){
  std::cout<<"hello";
}
```

C++ is not Java, `main` resides at the global scope, not as a class member.

Also, it's `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`.

Whatever tutorial or book you're following... it isn't any good.

Comment: I did this work but it does not know yet and it thinks that cout is a variable.

Comment: @BastianGata `cout` **is** a variable, yes. It's declared as `extern ostream&`. If you have this code and it doesn't work, your compiler is broken. See http://ideone.com/6BkTt

Comment: I think my compiler has a problem because I run other code in this site that you said  it did not have any problem.thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put that `#include` at the top of your file; including headers in the middle of a class will do weird, weird things! At the very least, it will embed all the names in the header into your class; most likely, it will simply fail to compile.

Furthermore, modern C++ puts `cout` and essentially every other symbol defined in the standard library into a namespace named `std`, so you need to write `std::cout`, or put "using namespace std;" before your class definition, but after the `#include.`

Comment: Don't forget it's iostream, not iostream.h

Comment: Indeed; I missed `main` inside the class, too. I think you win this round, I'm voting for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- The #include statement has to be outside the class declaration. It is good practise to put those at the top of the file and not scatter them through the file as it makes it much easier to check for dependencies in your code by eyeballing the top of the file instead of searching the whole file for #includes.
- Your main() function also has to be declared and defined outside the class. In contrast to Jave, main() in C and C++ is a standalone function.
- As mentioned, cin and cout live in the std namespace. I would recommend referring to them with the fully qualified name (ie, std::cin and std::cout), although you can use `using std::cin;` and `using std::cout;` either inside the function or in your implementation file *after* all includes
- You are including iostream.h - that is the "wrong" file as that is for the old iostreams library. The correct include for the standard compliant iostreams is `<iostream>`